# C# Log SMB file access

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi, instrumentation, wql

I'm trying to make a simple log of files transferred via SMB.

This works with Windows 8 or higher:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\Microsoft\Windows\SMB");

var query = new WqlEventQuery(

@"SELECT * 
  FROM 
      __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 
  WHERE 
      TargetInstance ISA 'MSFT_SmbOpenFile'"

);

ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(HandleEvent);

watcher.Start();

....
```

[But it does not work for windows 7 or lower. (Run-time requirements)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830479(v=vs.85).aspx)

Is there a similar solution that is compatible at least with windows 7?

**1º Edit**

It looks possible because this Windows 7 module does this task:

Computer Management (I'm seeing this information on windows 7)

[image: mmc.exe]

**2º Edit**

To clarify the purpose. I am building a [DLP application (Data Loss Prevention)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_loss_prevention_software). I need to monitor and log files accessed via windows share (user, filename) and eventually block this access at the moment the user request the file.

Comment: You can look at the NET family of commands - `net files` - gives the [list of open files](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490702.aspx). `net session` gives [the list of sessions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490711.aspx).

Comment: Great Subbu, I'm taking a look at the documentation now, looking for something event based, so I can be notified instead of running the command consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, this is a partial answer. It may be useful though, and it does not fit into a comment.

It seems you could try with [`Win32_ConnectionShare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394109(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`Win32_ServerConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394416(v=vs.85).aspx).
It is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126545/is-it-possible-to-programatically-log-access-to-a-windows-share-smb-share-usin), for instance.

Still, I am not sure you can use it to capture the event.
Combining all your requirements is challenging (that's why you set the bounty!)

Related info:

**https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17803/A-PC-Audit-Application-in-C**

[Detect File Read in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621661/detect-file-read-in-c-sharp)

[Is it possible to programatically log access to a windows share (SMB share) using the .Net framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126545/is-it-possible-to-programatically-log-access-to-a-windows-share-smb-share-usin)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

[SACL on Services using C# || get a handle to a service that has the ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY rights using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426295/sacl-on-services-using-c-sharp-get-a-handle-to-a-service-that-has-the-access)

https://www.netfort.com/blog/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/08/26/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers/

https://superuser.com/questions/783950/how-to-display-currently-connected-users-workstations-to-a-windows-smb-share

https://stackoverflow.com/a/154758/2707864

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365433(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726966.aspx

Comment: Hi @sancho.s, tks for reply. I've seen this feature before I post. This is the first related question in the list. Although it is something close to what I need, it is not event-driven and will not allow me to cancel the read request. Could you please post an example?

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves - You are right. Please see updated answer.